# On click not working - jquery

Tags: jquery

I am going nuts trying to figure out why this is no longer working.

The .on(click) does not fire at all.  I tried console.log, alerts, nothing is working.  I need a second pair of eyes to look at this.

JS:

```
var $gridStore;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover(); 

    //testing
    var currentPage = document.location.href;

    if (currentPage.match(/outfits\/$/) || currentPage.match(/outfits\/[a-z-#]+$/)) {
        if ($(window).width() > 992) {
            $('div#side-nav').show();
        } else {
            $('div#side-nav-mb').show();
        }
        $('ul#letter-subcategories').hide();
        $('ul li.main-nav').removeClass('active');
        $('li#menu-outfits').addClass('active');
    } else if (currentPage.match(/outfits\/[a-z-]+/)) {
        $('div#side-nav-mb').hide();
        $('div#side-nav').hide();
        $('ul#letter-subcategories').hide();
        $('ul li.main-nav').removeClass('active');
        $('li#menu-outfits').addClass('active');
    } else if (currentPage.match(/directory/)) {
        $('div#side-nav-mb').hide();
        $('div#side-nav').hide();
        $('ul#letter-subcategories').show();
        $('ul li.main-nav').removeClass('active');
        $('li#store-directory').addClass('active');
    } else if (currentPage.match(/magazine/)) {
        $('div#side-nav-mb').hide();
        $('div#side-nav').hide();
        $('ul#letter-subcategories').hide();
        $('ul li.main-nav').removeClass('active');
        $('li#magazine').addClass('active');
    } else if (currentPage.match(/models/)) {
        $('div#side-nav-mb').hide();
        $('div#side-nav').hide();
        $('ul#letter-subcategories').hide();
        $('ul li.main-nav').removeClass('active');
        $('li#models').addClass('active');
    } else {
        $('div#side-nav-mb').hide();
        $('div#side-nav').hide();
        $('ul#letter-subcategories').hide();
        $('ul li.main-nav').removeClass('active');
    }

    //initialize isotope
    $gridStore = $('#store-listings');
    $gridStore.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.store-listing-item',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.store-listing-item'
        }
    });

    $('div.row').has($('div.carousel')).css('margin-left', '-15px');
    $('div.row').has($('div.carousel')).css('margin-right', '-15px');
});

$(window).load(function() {
    var $grid = $('#outfits');
    $grid.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.outfit-item',
        layoutMode: 'fitRows',
        filter: '*'
    });
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress( function() {
        $grid.isotope('layout');
    });
});

$('ul.store-subcats li.subfilter a').each(function() {
    var clickedFilter;
    $gridStore = $('#store-listings');
    $(this).on('click', function() {
    clickedFilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    alert('i am clicked' + clickedFilter);
    if ( clickedFilter !== '*' ) {
        clickedFilter = clickedFilter + ', .stamp';
    }
    $gridStore.isotope({ filter: clickedFilter });
    location.hash = encodeURIComponent( clickedFilter.replace(/.(number-|letter-)/i, '').replace(/, .stamp/i, '') );
    $('ul.store-subcats li.subfilter').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
//$('span.how-many-stores').text();
var isIsotopeInit = false;
function onHashchange() {
    var hashFilter = getHashFilter();
    var newFilter;
    if ( !hashFilter && isIsotopeInit ) {
        return;
    }
    isIsotopeInit = true;
    if (hashFilter == 'number') {
        newFilter = '.number-' + hashFilter;
    } else {
        newFilter = '.letter-' + hashFilter;
    }
    // filter isotope
    $gridStore.isotope({
        itemSelector: '.store-listing-item',
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.col-md-12'
        },
        filter: newFilter + ', .stamp'
    });
}
$(window).on( 'hashchange', onHashchange );
// trigger event handler to init Isotope
onHashchange();
});
$('ul.store-subcats li.letter-all a').on('click', function() {
    $gridStore = $('#store-listings');
    $gridStore.isotope({ filter: '*' });
    removeHash();
    $('ul.store-subcats li.subfilter').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please, post your html code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The block where you define the onclick functions is missing a `});` at the end - it should look something like this:

```
$('ul.store-subcats li.subfilter a').each(function() {
  var clickedFilter;
  $gridStore = $('#store-listings');
  $(this).on('click', function() {
    clickedFilter = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    alert('i am clicked' + clickedFilter);
    if ( clickedFilter !== '*' ) {
      clickedFilter = clickedFilter + ', .stamp';
    }
    $gridStore.isotope({ filter: clickedFilter });
    location.hash = encodeURIComponent( clickedFilter.replace(/.(number-|letter-)/i, '').replace(/, .stamp/i, '') );
    $('ul.store-subcats li.subfilter').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I am now having another issue, but I will post that in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

First, check your class selector (loop result where you raise the on click). Are you sure that it returns something? The on click should be raised for each element that is selected by your selector so if it return nothing, sure that on click never happen